# npm run dev and run start produce TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE] and [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, git, visual-studio-code, npm, next.js

I get this error when running npm run dev:

```
PS C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail> npm run dev

> nortech_retail@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.local

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at Object.relative (node:path:498:5)
    at Watchpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:1420:55)
    at Watchpack.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Watchpack._onTimeout (C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\watchpack\watchpack.js:1:37727)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "to" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at Object.relative (node:path:498:5)
    at Watchpack.<anonymous> (C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:1420:55)
    at Watchpack.emit (node:events:514:28)
    at Watchpack._onTimeout (C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\watchpack\watchpack.js:1:37727)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}
```

I get this error when running npm start:

```
PS C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail> npm run start

> nortech_retail@0.1.0 start
> next start

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail\.next\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\19043\\node_projects\\nortech_retail\\.next\\BUILD_ID'
}
PS C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail>
```

npm run build prints:

```
PS C:\Users\19043\node_projects\nortech_retail> npm run build

> nortech_retail@0.1.0 build
> next build

   ▲ Next.js 14.1.3
   - Environments: .env.local

   Creating an optimized production build ...
 ✓ Compiled successfully

./components/image/LinkUnder.js
13:7  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
13:7  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./components/image/ShuffleGallery.js
11:7  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
12:7  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
13:7  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element

./components/image/SlideGallery.js
39:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'handleTransitionEnd'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
58:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'startInterval' and 'stopInterval'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
63:9  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
63:9  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./components/product/ProductContainer.js
28:24  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
28:24  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./src/app/(admin)/admin/add/components/GetOptionsSelect.js
31:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'table'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/app/(admin)/admin/add/components/GetOptionsSelectWJoin.js
35:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'join' and 'table'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/app/(admin)/admin/add/components/PhotoUploadForm.js
25:5  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
25:5  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

./src/app/(admin)/admin/add/components/SetProductType.js
47:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setError'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. If 'setError' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
54:8  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'configMap' and 'setConfig'. Either include them or remove the dependency array. If 'setConfig' changes too often, find the parent component that defines it and wrap that definition in useCallback.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/app/(customer)/checkout/payment/PaymentCollection.js
45:6  Warning: React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'clientSecret' and 'paymentAttempted'. Either include them or remove the dependency array.  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

./src/app/(customer)/products/all/components/ProductThumbnail.js
21:9  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
23:11  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element

./src/app/(customer)/uiTest/ProductContainerImageGallery.js
13:9  Warning: Using `<img>` could result in slower LCP and higher bandwidth. Consider using `<Image />` from `next/image` to automatically optimize images. This may incur additional usage or cost from your provider. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-img-element  @next/next/no-img-element
13:9  Warning: img elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text
29:37  Warning: Image elements must have an alt prop, either with meaningful text, or an empty string for decorative images.  jsx-a11y/alt-text

info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types
 ✓ Collecting page data
   Generating static pages (17/19) [=== ]
[ 19, 16, 17, 18 ]
 ✓ Generating static pages (19/19)
 ✓ Collecting build traces
 ✓ Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                               Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /                                     4.51 kB         120 kB
├ ○ /_not-found                           885 B          85.5 kB
├ ○ /admin                                140 B          84.7 kB
├ ○ /admin/add                            20.3 kB         129 kB
├ ○ /admin/products                       2.05 kB         111 kB
├ ○ /admin/querytest                      25.7 kB         163 kB
├ ○ /cart                                 3.11 kB         119 kB
├ ○ /checkout/complete                    862 B          85.5 kB
├ ○ /checkout/intent                      3.55 kB         112 kB
├ ○ /checkout/payment                     7.59 kB        92.2 kB
├ ○ /help                                 140 B          84.7 kB
├ ○ /order                                5.2 kB         89.8 kB
├ ○ /orderstatus                          676 B          85.3 kB
├ ○ /products/all                         347 B          84.9 kB
├ ○ /uiLaboratory                         879 B           114 kB
└ ○ /uiTest                               2.03 kB        93.4 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all             84.6 kB
  ├ chunks/69-46f60afa782793ea.js         29 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-7573f80532d3a28d.js   53.4 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)           2.17 kB

Route (pages)                             Size     First Load JS
┌ λ /api/neworder                         0 B            79.2 kB
├ λ /api/order/confirm                    0 B            79.2 kB
├ λ /api/order/confirm-old                0 B            79.2 kB
├ λ /api/order/intent                     0 B            79.2 kB
├ λ /api/order/status                     0 B            79.2 kB
├ λ /api/shipstation                      0 B            79.2 kB
└ λ /api/stripe/payment-intent            0 B            79.2 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all             79.2 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-aec844d2ccbe7592.js  45.2 kB
  ├ chunks/main-bd7ddb9be6964a65.js       31.8 kB
  └ other shared chunks (total)           2.14 kB

○  (Static)   prerendered as static content
λ  (Dynamic)  server-rendered on demand using Node.js
```

I have tried:

1. deleting package-lock.json, node_modules, .next files/directories and running npm install
2. clearing the cache with --force
3. every sequence of the last 2 steps
4. rolling back the node version
5. rolling forward the node version
6. every sequence of 1, 2, 4, and 5
7. moving the root folder to another directory
8. every sequence of 1, 2, 4, and 5 again
9. crying

I updated my node version 2 nights ago

The error first started appearing last night

newly installed packages:

1. express

newly deleted packages:

1. express

I was working on an api route when it started appearing.

My environment variables are current across all 3 systems I work on.

Vercel shows no errors when building for deploy.

My questions are:

1. How do I know where to look? I see where the errors are occurring, but I don't know what is causing the error.
2. Should I hang up the gloves and become a frontiersman?

### Edit

I rolled back my project (GitHub) to identify the breaking commit. I learned there were several working commits after I updated Node and installed/removed express. I removed all of the files modified in the commit and ran npm run dev one by one. No change. Not sure what this means, but I hope it helps! I will keep troubleshooting. Oh, and in regard to the npm build error, I checked to make sure the BUILD_ID file was indeed there with a string inside.

### Edit

It dawned on me that I forgot to update node on my work computer. Now, the breaking commit was the first push from my work computer after pushing from my home computer. Not sure if that could cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out.... It was me!

What was throwing me was the error wasn't presented in a pretty way by next, so I assumed it had to be an environment issue. I was afraid to even look in the files where the error was thrown because I'm an amateur dev and this is a build file. I don't even want to look in there!

To solve this error, I went to the file where the error was thrown:`\node_modules\next\dist\server\lib\router-utils\setup-dev-bundler.js:1421:55` and ran a console.log of the offending variables.

What was the issue? I had a file and a directory with the same name in my api directory.... hours of my life just gone for no good reason.

Morals of the story:

1. Don't be afraid to look in these forbidden files. At the end of the day, it's still javascript.
2. Even when you don't think you're the problem, you're probably the problem.